# looking for correct regular expression for pattern match in javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried searching stackoverflow for various combination but some or other thing stops working.

I am new to REGEX.

My input is `<abc.1.1.1 or abc.1.1 or abc.1 -->` case insensitive digits can be between 1-9 positive

```
var pattern= /[a-zA-Z].[1-9].[1-9].[1-9]$/;
```

the above pattern still accepts `abc.a1.b.1`

I am trying for following patterns 
abc.1.1.1
or
abc.1.1
or
abc.1

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use literal `.` as just `.` means "any character" Also you could improve it a bit using `global` and `ignoreCase` flags. Also use anchors `^` and `$`

```
var pattern= /^[a-z]+\.(([1-9]\.))+[1-9]$/ig;
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/jH4sP7/2)

Comment: var pattern= /[a-zA-Z]\.[1-9]\.[1-9]\.[1-9]/g; this one worked but it still accepts abc.1.1.1.1.1.1 there is no limit

Comment: var pattern= /[a-z]\.(([1-9]\.)+)?[1-9]/ig; this one still accepts alphabets in place of digits

Comment: @user2202257 check it now

Comment: sorry still not working. now it accepts even alphanumeric and no limit abc.1c.1d.1.1.1.1.c is showing true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66467/discussion-between-user2202257-and-amit-joki).

Answer (score 2):

This pattern will work

```
var pattern = /[a-z]*\.([0-9]\.?){,3}/i;
```

Comment: Ok try this /[a-z]*\.([0-9]\.?){0,3}/i. Weird but javascript regex is not working with {,3}. Try this out http://rubular.com/ for your tests

Answer (score 2):

[image: Your]

```
try this code
[a-z]+\.((([1-9]\.))*[1-9]+)*
```